# How can I prevent Microsoft Search Server from indexing hidden text in my web page

Tags: windows, search-server

I am using Microsoft Search Server 2010 Express to spider a web site and provide search facilities to the site users. In the html of the site, we have various elements that are hidden by means of a css class. For example:

```
<p class="hidden">Go to <a href="#mainNav" title="main menu">main menu</a></p>
```

Such text is intended to provide additional assistance for the visually impaired, and is not meaningful in the context of search results.

How can I configure Search Server so that it doesn't include text like this in the hit context of a result?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with some help from a colleague. The solution was to create an ASP.NET control which detects the user agent. If it's the search crawler, the output is not rendered.

Comment: -1. This is not an answer to the quesiton, which was about "a Website" and did not indicate it was YOUR site and you are willing to reprogram it (which is then a stackoverflow.com qustion, not one for System admins). As such, the question did not get answered - though obviously that was you not asking the correct question.

Comment: To be honest, this looks like a fairly arbitrary downvote. Was it the question or the answer you didn't like? There is plenty of information in the question to indicate that it's a site controlled by me. For starters, why would anyone use Search Server to spider /someone else's/ site? I mention that we want to provide search facilities to site users, etc.

Comment: But you are right that it isn't the answer I was looking for. I have yet to find a way to configure search server to solve this. But the solution I ended up with did the job. If anyone comes with a better solution, they'll get the tick.